# Trouble with Django email through gmail, always as spam

Tags: python, django, email, gmail-imap

In Django, I have an app that send email through an gmail account.
This is my settings.py configuration

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'thepassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

And the way to send emails (in views.py):

```
from_email = 'user@gmail.com' #look that is equal to EMAIL_HOST_USER
template_html = 'my_template.html'
subject = u'The subject'

html_content = render_to_string(template_html, {})

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, ['the_gmail_user@gmail.com'])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

The user always receive as SPAM.
It's something that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

P.s: The same issue occurs in Django 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6, so it's version agnostic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code...

Could be that your email has been flagged as spam by other users, or by Google (sending too many? Message content?). Try a different email service? Gmail isn't really designed for application level email service, but rather to be used by individuals.

I've recently switched to [MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/) and their free tier has enough capacity. There are other options out there as well.

Comment: Thanks @Trik, I currently use Mandrill

Comment: If you're using mandrill, make sure to set your DKIM and SPF records.